# Logitech software script

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I have a script for a Logitech mouse.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
repeat
if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
repeat
MoveMouseRelative(0,6)
Sleep(9)
until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
end
until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
end
end
end
```

I'm a super beginner, but I'm trying to change the "if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then" line so I can assign it to another key instead of capslock, preferably I'd like to change it to backspace. I'm also on a 60% keyboard if that makes any difference.

The script works so when I press capslock it activates, and if pressed again it turns off.
I'd like it to be the same way with the new key bind.

I just don't know how to write the code to assign a new key bind and also have it work in the Logitech software.

Comment: LGS/GHub is unable to monitor status of usual keys on a keyboard.  It does not see whether Backspace is pressed or not.  It can see only mouse buttons, Shift/Ctrl/Alt, Locks(Scroll/Caps/Num).  For example, you can toggle the script with LeftCtrl+LeftShift+RightMouseButton.  Or with MouseButton4+MouseButton5.  Or with MouseButton8 if you have such button on your Logitech gaming mouse.

Comment: BTW, does your kb have LEDs for Scroll/Caps/Num-Lock (despite it does not have keys for them)?

Comment: Yeah the Caps lock turns red when active

Comment: Does your kb has LEDs for keys that are absent (Scroll/Num-Lock)?

Comment: So, what is the key/button combination you want to toggle the script with?

Comment: I resolved it. I swapped it to scroll lock, Thanks for all the help.